# JSON: Stripping file of unnecessary information in python

Tags: python, json, flask

I'm working on a simple web app that pulls query information from a news article api. I'm looking to reduce client-side processing by stripping a json file of unnecessary information within my flask server. I want to store the edited json in a database (currently just locally in code below).

Currently my python code looks like:

```
def get_query(query):
    response = urllib2.urlopen(link + '?q=' + query + '&fl=' + fields + '&api-key=' + key)
    result = response.read()
    # store json locally 
    with open('static/json/' + query + '.json', 'w') as stored_json:
      json.dump(result, stored_json)
    with open('static/json/' + query + '.json', 'r') as stored_json:    
      return json.load(stored_json)
```

My issues are:

**a)** I am unsure of how to properly edit the json. Currently in my javascript I am using the data on my ajax call as:

```
data.response.docs[i].headline.main;
```

where I would rather just store and return the object docs as a json. I know variable result in my python code is a string so I cannot write and return result.response.docs. I tried returning `response.response.docs` but I realize this is incorrect.

**b)** My last four lines seem redundant, I was wondering how to place my return within my first open block. I tried both `'w+'` and `'r+'` with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if I am getting your question completely, but it sounds like what you want to do is:

```
1) receive the response
2) parse the json into a Python object
3) filter the data
4) store the filtered data locally (in a database, file, etc)
5) return the filtered data to the client
```

I am supposing that your json.dump / json.load combination was intended to get the json string into a format that you can manipulate easily (i.e. a Python object). If so, the json.loads (emphasis on the s) does what you need. Try something like this:

```
import json

def get_query(query):
    response = urllib2.urlopen(...)
    result = json.loads(response.read())

    # result is a regular Python object holding the data from the json response

    filtered = filter_the_data(result)

    # filter_the_data is some function that manipulates data

    with open('outfile.json', 'w') as outfile:
        # here dump (no s) is used to serialize the data
        # back to json and store it on the filesystem as outfile.json
        json.dump(filtered, outfile)

    ...
```

At this point you have saved the data locally, and you still hold a reference to the filtered data. You can re-serialize it and send it to the client easily using Flask's [jsonify](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/) function

Hope it helps